# Making imports explicit in PyQGIS and PyQt

Tags: python, pyqgis, import, pyqt5, pycharm

There is a QGIS plugin based on the PyQGIS/PyQt code with some imports defined in the beginning:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgspasswordlineedit import QgsPasswordLineEdit
```

Due to my personal desire and the [Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python), I would like to make my imports explicit instead of implicit. How can I implement that?

So, instead of the `from qgis.core import *` it should be `from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, Qgis`.

I did the above attempt manually, maybe there is an automated way. Perhaps, I can solve it with my IDLE - PyCharm.

I am aware that this is a pure StackOverflow question, however, there might be some PyQGIS/PyQt tricks for my issue available.

---

**References:**

- [Python Like You Mean It | Import: Modules and Packages](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module5_OddsAndEnds/Modules_and_Packages.html#Import:-Modules-and-Packages)

Comment: You can try this tool, specifically created for that : https://www.asmeurer.com/removestar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as was mentioned by @J.Monticolo in a comment: [`removestar`](https://pypi.org/project/removestar/) package is a nice option.

> Tool to automatically replace import * imports in Python files with
> explicit imports
>
> Requires [`pyflakes`](https://pypi.org/project/pyflakes/).
>
> Current limitations:
>
> - Assumes only names in the current file are used by star imports (e.g., it won’t work to replace star imports in `__init__.py`).

PyQGIS must be available in the same Python environment where the `removestar` would be installed.

---

**References:**

- [Is there an IDE/utility to refactor Python * imports to use standard module.member syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677061/is-there-an-ide-utility-to-refactor-python-imports-to-use-standard-module-memb)